# Updating Firefox toolbarbutton using listStyleImage attribute

Tags: css, dom, firefox-addon, xul

I am trying to update the css attribute for a toolbarbutton but the following does not work:

`document.getElementById('toolbar-button').style.listStyleImage = url("chrome://ext/skin/toolbar-button-add.png");`

Comment: But, what element for the `#toolbar-button` are you using?

Comment: @Strelok using `toolbarbutton` (edited question)

Comment: Is your CSS included correctly according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Adding_Toolbars_and_Toolbar_Buttons? Is the path to the image correct?

Comment: @Strelok It displays fine when it first loads using the CSS. I'm just having a problem when I try to update the image via JavaScript from the one originally set to a new one. I assume the paths are absolute when they start with chrome://... Maybe FF embeds the image?

Comment: Is that line of code you posted directly copy and pasted from your code? Because if it is, you are missing the `'` around the value. It should be `document.getElementById('toolbar-button').style.listStyleImage = 'url("chrome://ext/skin/toolbar-button-add.png")';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that line of code you posted directly copy and pasted from your code?

Because if it is, you are missing the `'` around the value. It should be

```
document.getElementById('toolbar-button').style.listStyleImage = 'url("chrome://ext/skin/toolbar-button-add.png")';
```

Always watch the debug console as this would have been revealed in the console as something like `'url': is not a function` or something like that.